# Is there a way yo use the result of a sql query in a where when making a form submition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to use a sql query to get the id from the last inserted row in my table and wanted to use this id in another sql query, where I update the phone number, but really can't get this to work.
Credentials are working fine and i erased for security reasons.
Sorry for any error, new to programming.

My code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=','','');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //insert data 

$insertid = "SELECT id FROM dados ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";//the first query where i get the id

    if(isset($_POST['telefone'])){

      $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE dados SET telefone=? WHERE id = ($insertid) "); //where i wanted to use the id
      $sql->execute(($_POST['telefone']));
    //  echo 'telefone inserido com sucesso';
    }
?>
```

But i keep getting the error: Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given on line 28 ($sql->execute(($_POST['telefone']));)

Comment: Side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Not related to the error you get, but you can simplify your code in a single query: `UPDATE dados SET telefone=?  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: thanks @forpas, that's what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

[`PDOStatement::execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) does expect first parameter to be an array. So you should change this:

```php
$sql->execute(($_POST['telefone']));
```

with this:

```php
$sql->execute([$_POST['telefone']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did not needed to use 2 queries, only one, it goes like:

`$sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE dados SET telefone=?  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");`

Thanks to @forpas for clarifying!!